# How to tell if wine is rooted?

Tags: wine, root, system, winetricks

I’ve heard that wine can install window viruses if rooted. How can I tell if my wine is rooted?

Comment: Where did you heard/red that. Can you link back to the source, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine by default runs programs as admin within itself, but wine can even be broken by trying to run it as root. Never run it as root. To tell if it is "rooted" just see what command you use to launch it. If it includes "sudo" or "gksudo" or even "kdesudo" you are running it as root. Wine is subject to viruses in the same way a non admin windows account can be. Just make sure what you are running in it is safe and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, i just wasn’t sure if i would get i virus through a web site or though a torrent. Im a noob...

Comment: you couldn't get it while browsing the web unless it's meant for linux specifically, and when it comes to torrents so long as you download non-pirated content mainly isos and such you SHOULD be fine

Comment: ps it's kind of a pet peeve of mine but torrents do not make downloading paid content for free legal

Comment: Thank you, now I feel fine not getting a browser firewall!

Comment: even still there is a stock firewall and if you value the data on your computer you would get a good one\

Comment: also if I answered your question feel free to mark my answer as `"the one"` :P